# Filtering arrays using search form [php]

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, multidimensional-array

I have array list as my data and html form for my search filtering.
What I want to achieve is to filter the array using search form. The search form already had value in select option. I have 3 values to use in filtering -> `location, type and status`.
Here how it looks like:

```html
<form name="search-form" method="GET">
   <div class="keyword-input"><input type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="Keyword"></div>
   <div class="searchform-title">Location</div>
   <div style="margin-bottom:20px;">
      <select name="location" style="width:100%; padding:5px">
         <option value='' selected>Any</option>
         <option value='A city'>A city</option>
         <option value='B City'>B City</option>
         <option value='C city'>C city</option>
         <option value='D city'>D city</option>
         <option value='L city'>L city</option>
         <option value='M city'>M city</option>
         <option value='T city'>T city</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class="searchform-title">Type</div>
   <div style="margin-bottom:20px;">
      <select name="type" style="width:100%; padding:5px">
         <option value='' selected>Any</option>
         <option value='Type 1'>Type 1</option>
         <option value='Type 2'>Type 2</option>
         <option value='Type 3'>Type 3</option>
         <option value='Type 4'>Type 4</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class="searchform-title">Status</div>
   <div style="margin-bottom:20px;">
      <select name="status" style="width:100%; padding:5px">
         <option value='' selected>Any</option>
         <option value='New'>New</option>
         <option value='Old'>Old</option>
         <option value='Under'>Under</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <input class="proj-search-btn" type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Using the $_GET function I can know what filtering was the user wants. (e.g from url `search.php?location=A+city&type=Type+2&status=`)

Now my array list look like this:

```
$products = array();

       $products[] = array('name'=> 'Product 1','description' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.', 'location' => 'A city', 'type' => 'Type 1', '

status' => 'new', 'tags'=>'', 'page_url'=>'p1.html', 'image'=>'products/assets/images/1/prod-image.jpg');

    $products[] = array('name'=> 'Product 2','description' => 'Donec eleifend quam neque, ut mollis massa aliquet id.', 'location' => 'B city', 'type' => 'Type 1', 'status' => 'under', 'tags'=>'', 'page_url'=>'p2.html', 'image'=>'products/assets/images/2/prod-image.jpg');

    $products[] = array('name'=> 'Product 3','description' => 'Nam non tristique mi.', 'location' => 'A city', 'type' => 'Type 3', 'status' => 'new', 'tags'=>'', 'page_url'=>'p3.html', 'image'=>'products/assets/images/3/prod-image.jpg');

    $products[] = array('name'=> 'Product 4','description' => 'Vestibulum accumsan dolor id orci gravida viverra.', 'location' => 'C city', 'type' => 'Type 2', 'status' => 'new', 'tags'=>'', 'page_url'=>'p4.html', 'image'=>'products/assets/images/4/prod-image.jpg');
```

Using the search form, the data arrays will be filtered to location, type and status then show the result of filtering.

Consider the ff. issue I encountered:

- Is it possible to look like the output of SQL query condition similar to `WHERE location = $_GET['location'] AND type = $_GET['type'] AND status = $_GET['status']`.
- When the user select **any location** it will filter only the type and status selected by the user (regardless of the location, bec. it is selected as **any**)
- The same as well when the user select **any** to both `location` or `type` and selected `status` as **new**.
- Any combination of selected value in filtering should work.

This is what I have tried so far through searching [Sample here](http://ideone.com/Lc58Tj)

Any help is appreciated. I am learning new things in PHP and arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [array_filter](http://php.net/array-filter):

```
// assuming $products is an array of products...

if (isset($_GET['location']) && $_GET['location']!=='') {
    // only apply this filter if $_GET['location'] is set and is not blank:
    $products = array_filter($products, function($product) {
        // return TRUE (keep this product in the list) if its location matches
        return $product['location'] === $_GET['location'];
    });
}

// $products is now only the products whose location matched the selected location
// unless "All" was selected as the location, in which case $products is unchanged

// you can repeat the above code again for type and status to filter $products further
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This answered my question, and it's easy to follow.

Comment: I would just like to know how to sort all the array `$products` by product name after filtering?

Comment: You'll want to check out [usort()](http://php.net/usort) to do that. Example #2 on that link is close to the data you're dealing with.

Comment: One more question if you don't mind... from your code above, how can I filter the location which is `like` not equal to the value of the selected option. Example `return $product['location'] which is like $_GET['location'];` Because sometimes I typed some capital letters of location, type or status (`A city` or `a City` or `A City`).

Comment: Never mind my last question, I have to use `stripos` function. `return (stripos($product['location'], $_GET['location']) !== false);` ;)

Comment: You can also use [http://php.net/strtolower ](strtolower) to convert both strings to all lowercase.

Comment: Hi @BrileyHooper, your answer really help me developed my program. I have just another idea. Where in I am adding a search input text.. So the user can input any keyword (e.g product name or keyword from description etc).. then it will show the product that contains the keyword as well as the filtered 'location`, `type` and `status`.. Your response is appreciated.

Comment: What I have tried working is `$products = array_filter($products, function($product) use ($keyword) {
        return (stripos($product['description'], $keyword) !== false );` but this only filter the description..

Comment: in the `use ($keyword)` part of your callback function you can declare more than one variable that you want to use. So, you could do something like `function($product) use ($keyword, $location, $status) {
       return stripos($product['description'], $keyword) !== false
          && $product['location'] === $location
          && $product['status'] === $status;
    }`